# C# TypeInitiializationException

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a C# program running under Visual Studio 15 .NET Framework 4.5.2. It uses AutoMapper 4.1.1. It's been running fine for years. (I inherited it from someone else.) Just lately, it started erroring out at the line "AutoMappings.AutoMappings.CreateMaps();" Here's the relevant code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using IVGOffice.UserInterface;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace IVGOffice
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // Assign certification callback to allow for self-signed certs on the services
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(IVG.Common.Certificate.ValidateRemoteCertificate);
            AutoMappings.AutoMappings.CreateMaps();  // <----- Errors out here
```

It throws a System.TypeInitiializationException with inner error "Configuration system failed to initialize". It never actually enters into the AutoMappings class, so I don't think the problem is related to the class, but here's the beginning of it anyway:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using IVG.Common;
using IVG;

namespace IVGOffice.AutoMappings
{
    public static class AutoMappings
    {
        private static bool mapsCreated = false;
        private static Utilities2.Services services = new Utilities2.Services();

        public static void CreateMaps()
        {
            // AutoMapper CreateMap should only be called once in an application domain. If we call this twice, check and just leave the second time
            if (mapsCreated)
                return;

            // For every IAutomappedObject
            System.Reflection.Assembly assm =     System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
            var interfaceTypes = assm.GetTypes();
            var automappedTypes = interfaceTypes.Where(type => typeof(IAutomappedObject).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                && !type.IsAbstract
                && !type.IsInterface);
            foreach (var type in automappedTypes)
               ...
```

My coworker tried running the same code on his laptop and it worked fine, so there must be something going on with my copy of Visual Studio or my computer settings. I've tried running different versions of the program, rebooting, restoring the program from backup, etc. to no avail.

Anybody have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `TypeInitiializationException` means the static constructor or any static field initialization failed. You need to debug your code to find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit this today because I stupidly placed appSettings before the configSections in my app.config file.

The error possibly indicates that your config file contains illegal syntax/layout. I'd start your investigation there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the configuration, but not in app.config. I had added code to save and restore the window status, location, and size. These settings were saved into a new user.config file. The problem was that I had added this code to a new git repo. My boss had to approve the changes before merging them into the master repo. In the meantime, I had gone back to the master to start a new project. The master didn't have the new code, but the new user.config file was still there. For some reason, that seems to have confused the program. When my boss finally merged the new code and I updated my copy of the master, the problem went away. Thanks for your feedback.